# Draw simple Text in a MKPolygonView

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, drawrect

Hello I try to draw text in a MKPolygonView. I made a subclass of MKPolygonView and added it to my MKMapView. The Polygon shows up correctly, but I can't see the Text. Can anyone help me?

```
-(void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context{

  [super drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context];

  CGRect overallCGRect = [self rectForMapRect:self.overlay.boundingMapRect];
  UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold" size:20.0f]; 

  NSString * t= @"Test";
  [[UIColor redColor] set];
  [t drawInRect:overallCGRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that you need to use CoreGraphics for any kind of drawing in your drawMapRect override.  The code below has not been compiled so I can't guarantee that it will work out of the box, but something along these lines will probably do the job.

```
-(void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context{

  // The base implementation does nothing so this isn't needed
  //[super drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context];

  NSString * t= @"Test" ;
  CGPoint point = [self pointForMapPoint:mapRect.origin];

  CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  CGContextSelectFont (context, "Helvetica", 20.0f, kCGEncodingFontSpecific);
  CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, point.x, point.y, [t UTF8String], [t length]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be able to use the UIKit drawing by [pushing the context](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsPushContext) to the UI graphics context stack, then popping it afterwards, like so:

```
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
[[UIColor redColor] set];
[t drawInRect:...];
etc, etc.
UIGraphicsPopContext();
```