# How to Display Text on MKMapView

Tags: ios

I need to display a text on Mkmapview for example "100 meters", i know how to adding for example line using overlay. **But I have no clue how to add a text "**

any advice?

Thanks

Comment: [This related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825220/draw-text-in-circle-overlay) involves a circle overlay but you can probably use the same approach with a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an annotation and return a custom annotation view that draws it's text.