# Reusing custom drawn annotation view

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I've managed to draw numbers inside custom colored circle annotations (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825220/draw-text-in-circle-overlay)). I want to make some optimizations for my custom annotation class and I read about reusing.
My problem is if I make the stuff reusable, the annotation views get mixed on map which is a big problem.
The custom drawn annotation views cannot be reused ? Or is it somehow related to the view's annotaion ? I mean, the annotation stores the number to be drawn on its view, practically it's a 1to1 relationship between annotation and its view.

Here is my relevant code : 
Custom annotationview's init :

```
-(id)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier imageType:(int)imageType {

    self = [super initWithAnnotation: annotation reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier];
    if (self != nil)
    {
       if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CircleMarker class]]) 
       {
           // custom annotation class with some extra fields
           CircleMarker * clm = (CircleMarker * )annotation;
           self.locationMarker = clm; 

           //  ... setting frame and other stuff

           self.image = [self getImage];  /* this method DRAWS image based on clm */
           self.canShowCallout = NO;           
       }
...
}
```

And the delegate :

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    static NSString *reuseId_small = @"smallcircle"; 
    static NSString *reuseId_big   = @"bigcircle";   
    CircleAnnotationView * nca = nil;    
    if ((int)[self.mapView getZoomLevel] < ZOOM_LEVEL_FOR_NUMBERS)
        {
        nca = (CircleAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId_small];   
        if (nca == nil )
            nca = [[[CircleAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId_small imageType:2] autorelease];
        }
        else 
        {
        nca = (CircleAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId_big];  
        if ( nca == nil )
            nca = [[[CircleAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId_big imageType:1] autorelease];
        }
 return nca;
}
```

I've tried to replace the `self.image =` part with a custom `drawRect` function, but the result was the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Or, in these cases only the colored circles (the circle's background) can be reused and I should separate the drawn number from the background ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a call to prepareForReuse on the MKAnnotationView when it gets dequeued.  In this method you could check to see if the content needs redrawing.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I see this going inside your CircleAnnotationView code

Comment: Yeah, probably this is the best answer. After all I ended to separate the common background to be reusable, so I draw the content on a transparent circle which I put on the reused circles. Thanks anyway.