# How to create Text Overlay in an MKCircle (iOS MapKit Overlays)

Tags: ios, overlay, mapkit

I have searched far and wide for a proper solution but have yet to find any.

```
-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id)overlay 
{
    MKCircleView* circleView = [[[MKCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay] autorelease];
    circleView.fillColor=[UIColor redColor];
    return circleView;
}

-(void)overlay{
    MKCircle *circleOverlay;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(1.303819,103.7689956); //giza
    circleOverlay=[MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:coords radius:200];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:circleOverlay];

}
```

Is there a simple way to add a text into this circle?

Comment: See the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825220/draw-text-in-circle-overlay, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529217/is-there-away-to-add-text-using-paths-drawing