# MKpolyline title

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I added MKpolyline in my map using the following code.But it is not showing the title of polyline.Please help me to show the title.Thanks in advance.

```
self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:2];
self.routeLine.title = @"route1";
[mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
```

Comment: Unfortunately the title has to be drawn manually.  See the following for ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825220/draw-text-in-circle-overlay, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529217/is-there-away-to-add-text-using-paths-drawing

Comment: Another crude alternative might be to add a custom annotation with a UILabel near the polyline overlay.

Comment: Did you found any answer for this? I am struggling from so long haven't got anything working. Please help.