# Render Title of MKPolygon

Tags: objective-c, ios7, mkmapview, mkpolygon

I'm trying to render `MKPolygon` using the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *overlays = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (NSDictionary *state in states) {
            NSArray *points = [state valueForKeyPath:@"point"];

            NSInteger numberOfCoordinates = [points count];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D *polygonPoints = malloc(numberOfCoordinates * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));

            NSInteger index = 0;
            for (NSDictionary *pointDict in points) {
                polygonPoints[index] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[pointDict valueForKeyPath:@"latitude"] floatValue], [[pointDict valueForKeyPath:@"longitude"] floatValue]);
                index++;
            }

            MKPolygon *overlayPolygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:polygonPoints count:numberOfCoordinates];
            overlayPolygon.title = [state valueForKey:@"name"];

            [overlays addObject:overlayPolygon];

            free(polygonPoints);
        }
[self.stateMapView addOverlays:overlays];
```

I used the following code to provide stroke and fill colors:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 7_0);
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]])
    {
        MKPolygonRenderer *pv = [[MKPolygonRenderer alloc] initWithPolygon:overlay];

        pv.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
        pv.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        return pv;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Do I need to do something to render the Title? I think I should enable a configuration or something but I'm new to `MapView`. Or I need to create a `UILabel`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overlays don't automatically show their titles like annotations can (in their *callout* actually) so there's nothing you "need to do" or any configuration that you can enable.

A simple workaround to show titles on overlays is, as you suggest, to create a `UILabel`.
However, this `UILabel` should be added to an *annotation view* that is positioned at each overlay's center.

A minor drawback (or maybe not) to this method is that the titles will not scale with the zoom of the map -- they'll stay the same size and can eventually collide and overlay with other titles (but you may be ok with this).

To implement this approach:

1. For each overlay, add an annotation (using `addAnnotation:` or `addAnnotations:`) and set the `coordinate` to the approximate center of the overlay and the `title` to the overlay's title.

   Note that since `MKPolygon` implements *both* the `MKOverlay` *and* the `MKAnnotation` protocols, you don't necessarily need to create a separate annotation class or separate objects for each overlay.  `MKPolygon` automatically sets its `coordinate` property to the approximate center of the polygon so you don't need to calculate anything.  *You can just add the overlay objects themselves as the annotations.*  That's how the example below does it.
2. Implement the `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` delegate method and create an `MKAnnotationView` with a `UILabel` in it that displays the `title`.

Example:

```
[self.stateMapView addOverlays:overlays];

//After adding the overlays as "overlays",
//also add them as "annotations"...
[self.stateMapView addAnnotations:overlays];


//Implement the viewForAnnotation delegate method...
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        //show default blue dot for user location...
        return nil;
    }

    static NSString *reuseId = @"ann";
    MKAnnotationView *av = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
    if (av == nil)
    {
        av = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
        av.canShowCallout = NO;

        //add a UILabel in the view itself to show the title...
        UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
        titleLabel.tag = 42;
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
        [av addSubview:titleLabel];
        av.frame = titleLabel.frame;
    }
    else
    {
        av.annotation = annotation;
    }

    //find the UILabel and set the title HERE
    //so that it gets set whether we're re-using a view or not...
    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[av viewWithTag:42];
    titleLabel.text = annotation.title;

    return av;
}
```

The alternative approach is to create a custom overlay renderer and do all the drawing yourself (the polygon line, the stroke color, the fill color, and the text).  See [Draw text in circle overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825220/draw-text-in-circle-overlay) and [Is there a way to add text using Paths Drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529217/is-there-away-to-add-text-using-paths-drawing) for some ideas on how to implement that.

Comment: Also add this when creating the label otherwise `minimumScaleFactor` will have no effect: `titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;`.